# Bash new variable with other variable

Tags: bash, sed

I get the ip address like that :

```
Ip=`ifconfig | grep inet | grep -v -E 'inet6|127.0.0.1' | \
    tr -d [:alpha:] | tr -s [:space:] | cut -d: -f2`
```

I have an ip like this for instance : `10.1.0.76`

I want to make a new variable with the Ip variable to have another ip, for instance my new variable will return : `10.1.0.178`

Just the last number change, so I want to get just a part of Ip variable (10.1.0.) and add another number to the end.

I tried with sed but I always have mistakes like "there's no file call'd ..."

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use parameter expansion: It's simply: `${Ip%.*}.178`

`${Ip%.*}` is the ip with the last dot and everything after it removed. The `.178` is what you want to append after that.

Here it is in context:

```
# Your original expression
Ip=`ifconfig | grep inet | grep -v -E 'inet6|127.0.0.1' | \
    tr -d [:alpha:] | tr -s [:space:] | cut -d: -f2`

# assign a new variable with the ip with different end octet
newIp=${Ip%.*}.178

# Show new ip
echo "$newIp"
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, given that you have IP in a format x.y.z.w, you can use perl regex:

```
$ echo "120.20.31.78" | perl -pe 's/(.*)\..*/$1\.123/'
120.20.31.123
```

This will repace last number ("78") with "123".

So, in your case (assuming your "Ip" variable is set correctly), it would be:

```
Ip=ifconfig | grep inet | grep -v -E 'inet6|127.0.0.1' | tr -d [:alpha:] | tr -s [:space:] | cut -d: -f2 | perl -pe 's/(.*)\..*/$1\.123/'
```

Answer (score 0):

see this, I hope it is what you want:

```
kent$  echo $ip
10.1.0.76

kent$  echo $part
178

kent$  sed -r "s/(.*\.).*/\1$part/" <<< $ip
10.1.0.178
```

to set $ip with new value:

```
kent$  ip=$(sed -r "s/(.*\.).*/\1$part/" <<< $ip)

kent$  echo $ip
10.1.0.178
```